# what is the meaning of this sfx/onomatopoeia? ダシーン

Tags: translation, manga, onomatopoeia

dashi (ダシ) sometimes is for "run"

but this sfx is nothing about running!

example (the ball is a dough, they make bread)
[image]

Comment: if you could include an image of the page before and after this one, it might be easier to tell, but I think this is an example of a sound word representing a motion. although it could be a literal sound of some inanimate object...

Comment: There are several types of "sound words" in Japanese: Giseigo 擬声語 (Animal and human sounds.), Giongo 擬音語 (Actual sounds made by inanimate objects and nature.), Gitaigo 擬態語 (sounds describe conditions and states.), Giyougo 擬容語 (sounds describe movements and motions.), and Gijougo 擬情語 (sounds describe feelings.)

Comment: Is the first page :( . And is a timeslip so the others pages don't talk about it.  (In order, I think chronologically the first page is the last, because in the end they make bread and the black hair person cut the dough. So maybe ... the sfx is for cut the dough with fierce ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the scene, it's obviously used as a variant of [ダーン](http://thejadednetwork.com/sfx/browse/dan/). It's not a common onomatopoeia, and I don't think I have seen this elsewhere. [Mangaka often create original onomatopoeias](http://leodraco.blog120.fc2.com/blog-entry-377.html), and I think this is another example.

Comment: @NinoskaMiranda Typically, ダーン is the sound of a basketball hit on the wall/ground. It's not the sound of cutting something with a knife.